# Unable to tether iphone's personal wireless hotspot on 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, iphone

In Windows I could turn on person hotspot on the iphone, connect the iPhone via USB and it would recognize the iPhone hotspot and connect to it.

On Ubuntu 13.10, I can see my files on connecting to the iPhone but cannot see the network. iPhone tells me that there are three tethering options: Wireless, USB and Bluetooth. I would like to be able to use either of the first two options.

How can I use the iPhone personal hotspot with Ubuntu 13.10? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, the following package seems to solve my problem. The strange thing is, it never asked for a password (which does happen in windows) so might be a security issue for Apple in the future. (I tested it by switching off wifi to make sure I am using the 3G connection.)

[check this.](http://packages.debian.org/sid/net/ipheth-utils)